# How to template inline attributes in svelte?

Tags: svelte

In this repl example, how would I set the `style` attribute inline, without needing to duplicate the anchor tag?

https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.13.6&gist=0a2bd4376b2fe742fb0d233755c44796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Zac's answer, you could also [add a helper function](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.13.6&gist=9ad32a2ce8916175d52ff8f81d7ea6ce) that returned a style like so:

```
export default {
  helpers: {
    getStyle ( page ) {
      if ( page === 'about' ) return 'color: blue';
      return '';
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Just attempting to generalise this a bit more by adding a `.selected` style if a `pageName` parameter matches the current `page`:

https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.13.7&gist=484afa12e598418172bf2fd8d48dd3ad

However, I get `page is not defined`. I've tried `this.page`, `this.get(page)`, `this.get('page')`, `get(page)`, `get('page')`, but none work. How do you access something in your data object from a helper?

Comment: Helpers are pure functions, they don't have access to the component instance — you have to pass `page` in as an argument: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.13.7&gist=50804388af23a2837b7562d5df8200f6. Personally I would typically inline that as `{{page === 'about' ? 'selected' : ''}}`, but that's just my preference

Comment: Ah, right - inline is better. Thanks, and congrats on a great framework :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a computed property that forms the style, then put that in your template.

```
<a href="#" style="{{pageStyle}}">{{page}}</a>
<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      page: 'About'
    };
  },
  computed: {
    pageStyle: (page) => (page==="about" ? 'color: blue;' : '')
  }
}
</script>
```

Or even better, you could use classes to apply the style based on the pages name.

```
<a href="#" class="page__{{page}}">{{page}}</a>
<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      page: 'About'
    };
  }
}
</script>
<style>
page__About {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is vue not svelte

Comment: @chovy Why do you think that? This is svelte

Comment: Because it looks like vue. Svelte doesn't have `data() {}` vue does. afaik

Comment: Svelte v2, the current version when this post was made, supported data. Here is a reference https://v2.svelte.dev/guide